# Authenticate MongoDB shard cluster in Docker swarm

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4, docker

I am trying to put **authentication** to the mongo shard cluster which is running in docker swarm.

**docker-compose.yml file:**

```
version: "3.3"
services:
    cfg1-r1:
        image: mongo:3.4.9
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints: [node.hostname == ram-ThinkPad-E470]
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
        volumes:
            - /opt/mongosharddb/db-data:/var/lib/mongodb
            - /opt/mongosharddb/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
            - /opt/mongosharddb/mongodb-keyfile:/srv/mongodb-keyfile
        networks:
            - mongoshard
        command: ["mongod", "--configsvr", "--replSet", "rs0", "--dbpath", "/var/lib/mongodb", "--port", "27017"]
        #command: ["mongod", "--configsvr", "--replSet", "rs0", "--dbpath", "/var/lib/mongodb", "--port", "27017", "--keyFile", "/srv/mongodb-keyfile"]

    cfg2-r1:
        image: mongo:3.4.9
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints: [node.hostname == prasanna-ThinkPad-E470]
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
        volumes:
            - /opt/mongosharddb/db-data:/var/lib/mongodb
            - /opt/mongosharddb/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
            - /opt/mongosharddb/mongodb-keyfile:/srv/mongodb-keyfile
        networks:
            - mongoshard
        command: ["mongod", "--configsvr", "--replSet", "rs0", "--dbpath", "/var/lib/mongodb", "--port", "27017"]
        #command: ["mongod", "--configsvr", "--replSet", "rs0", "--dbpath", "/var/lib/mongodb", "--port", "27017", "--keyFile", "/srv/mongodb-keyfile"]

    shard1-repl1:
        image: mongo:3.4.9
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints: [node.hostname == prasanna-ThinkPad-E470]
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
        volumes:
            - /opt/mongosharddb/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
            - /opt/mongosharddb/db-shard:/var/lib/mongodb
            - /opt/mongosharddb/mongodb-keyfile:/srv/mongodb-keyfile
        networks:
            - mongoshard
        command: ["mongod", "--shardsvr", "--replSet", "s1-r1", "--dbpath", "/var/lib/mongodb", "--port", "27017"]
        #command: ["mongod", "--shardsvr", "--replSet", "s1-r1", "--dbpath", "/var/lib/mongodb", "--port", "27017", "--keyFile", "/srv/mongodb-keyfile"]

    shard2-repl1:
        image: mongo:3.4.9
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints: [node.hostname == Trisundhar]
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
        volumes:
            - /opt/mongosharddb/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
            - /opt/mongosharddb/db-shard:/var/lib/mongodb
            - /opt/mongosharddb/mongodb-keyfile:/srv/mongodb-keyfile
        networks:
            - mongoshard
        command: ["mongod", "--shardsvr", "--replSet", "s1-r1", "--dbpath", "/var/lib/mongodb", "--port", "27017"]
        #command: ["mongod", "--shardsvr", "--replSet", "s1-r1", "--dbpath", "/var/lib/mongodb", "--port", "27017", "--keyFile", "/srv/mongodb-keyfile"]

    shard1-repl2:
        image: mongo:3.4.9
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints: [node.hostname == Ravi-ThinkPad-E470]
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
        volumes:
            - /opt/mongosharddb/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
            - /opt/mongosharddb/db-shard:/var/lib/mongodb
            - /opt/mongosharddb/mongodb-keyfile:/srv/mongodb-keyfile
        networks:
            - mongoshard
        command: ["mongod", "--shardsvr", "--replSet", "s2-r2", "--dbpath", "/var/lib/mongodb", "--port", "27017"]
        #command: ["mongod", "--shardsvr", "--replSet", "s2-r2", "--dbpath", "/var/lib/mongodb", "--port", "27017", "--keyFile", "/srv/mongodb-keyfile"]

    shard2-repl2:
        image: mongo:3.4.9
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints: [node.hostname == Dsp-Lenovo]
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
        volumes:
            - /opt/mongosharddb/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
            - /opt/mongosharddb/db-shard:/var/lib/mongodb
            - /opt/mongosharddb/mongodb-keyfile:/srv/mongodb-keyfile
        networks:
            - mongoshard
        command: ["mongod", "--shardsvr", "--replSet", "s2-r2", "--dbpath", "/var/lib/mongodb", "--port", "27017"]
        #command: ["mongod", "--shardsvr", "--replSet", "s2-r2", "--dbpath", "/var/lib/mongodb", "--port", "27017", "--keyFile", "/srv/mongodb-keyfile"]

    shard1-repl3:
        image: mongo:3.4.9
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints: [node.hostname == Alu]
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
        volumes:
            - /opt/mongosharddb/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
            - /opt/mongosharddb/db-shard:/var/lib/mongodb
            - /opt/mongosharddb/mongodb-keyfile:/srv/mongodb-keyfile
        networks:
            - mongoshard
        command: ["mongod", "--shardsvr", "--replSet", "s3-r3", "--dbpath", "/var/lib/mongodb", "--port", "27017"]
        #command: ["mongod", "--shardsvr", "--replSet", "s3-r3", "--dbpath", "/var/lib/mongodb", "--port", "27017", "--keyFile", "/srv/mongodb-keyfile"]

    shard2-repl3:
        image: mongo:3.4.9
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints: [node.hostname == Acer-Idavalapati]
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
        volumes:
            - /opt/mongosharddb/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
            - /opt/mongosharddb/db-shard:/var/lib/mongodb
            - /opt/mongosharddb/mongodb-keyfile:/srv/mongodb-keyfile
        networks:
            - mongoshard
        command: ["mongod", "--shardsvr", "--replSet", "s3-r3", "--dbpath", "/var/lib/mongodb", "--port", "27017"]
        #command: ["mongod", "--shardsvr", "--replSet", "s3-r3", "--dbpath", "/var/lib/mongodb", "--port", "27017", "--keyFile", "/srv/mongodb-keyfile"]

    mongos:
        image: mongo:3.4.9
        deploy:
            replicas: 2
            placement:
                constraints: [node.hostname == ram-ThinkPad-E470]
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
        volumes:
            - /opt/mongosharddb/mongodb-keyfile:/srv/mongodb-keyfile
        networks:
            - mongoshard
        ports:
            - 27030:27017
        depends_on:
            - cfg1-r1
            - cfg2-r1
            - cfg3-r1
            - shard1-repl1
            - shard2-repl1
            - shard1-repl2
            - shard2-repl2
            - shard1-repl3
            - shard2-repl3
        command: ["mongos", "--configdb", "rs0/cfg1-r1:27017", "--port", "27017"]
        #command: ["mongos", "--configdb", "rs0/cfg1-r1:27017", "--port", "27017", "--keyFile", "/srv/mongodb-keyfile"]

networks:
    mongoshard:
        driver: overlay
        attachable: true
```

**Deploy:** sudo docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth --compose-file docker-compose.yml mongo

I initiated replica set of config server and shard servers. I added shards to mongos. When I put data in the database, sharing is happening among shard servers.

I have done this without authentication. Everything is going well.

But when I try to add authentication I am failing to do.

**Steps followed to enable authentication on MongoDB cluster in docker swarm:**

**Step1:** Created required data folders and generated key file and copied this key file to each node.

**Step2:** Deployed stack file in docker swarm without the key file.

**Step3:** Initiated config server and shard servers replica set.

**Step4:** Added users to the mongos, config servers and shard servers.

**Step5:** Changed the ownership of key file and mongod.conf file in each container.

**Ex:**sudo docker exec  bash -c 'chown -R mongodb:mongodb /srv/mongodb-keyfile /etc/mongod.conf'

**Step6:** Deployed docker-compose.yml (updated) again in docker swarm with the second command (With key fie). [It runs all containers with key file]

**Step7:** When I try to add shards to the mongos, I am getting error

```
mongos> sh.addShard("s3-r3/shard1-repl3:27017")
{
        "code" : 133,
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "could not find host matching read preference { mode: \"primary\" } for set s3-r3"
}
```

I have setup authentication on nodes(without docker). It's working there properly.

**Edit:** If I add shards to mongos before authentication then sharding is not happening. All the data is going to only one shard (Eg: s3-r3).

**logs of other shards (services):**

```
mongo_shard1-repl1.1.fgq9hukdsvmf@prasanna-ThinkPad-E470    | 2017-10-20T07:15:09.338+0000 W NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor-0] No primary detected for set s1-r1
mongo_shard1-repl1.1.fgq9hukdsvmf@prasanna-ThinkPad-E470    | 2017-10-20T07:15:19.338+0000 W NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor-0] Failed to connect to 10.0.6.37:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
```

Answer (score 1):

As per MongoDB BOL [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/) Use the [sh.addShard()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/sh.addShard/#sh.addShard) method to add each shard to the cluster. If the shard is a replica set, specify the name of the replica set and specify a member of the set. In production deployments, all shards should be replica sets.

**The following operation adds a single shard replica set to the cluster**:

```
sh.addShard( "<replSetName>/s1-mongo1.example.net:27017")
```

**The following operation is an example of adding a standalone mongod shard to the cluster**:

```
sh.addShard( "s1-mongo1.example.net:27017")
```

Repeat these steps until the cluster includes all shards.

**Enable Sharding for a Database**

To proceed, you must be connected to a [mongos](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongos/#bin.mongos) associated to the target sharded cluster.

Before you can shard a collection, you must enable sharding for the collection’s database. Enabling sharding for a database does not redistribute data but make it possible to shard the collections in that database.

Once you enable `sharding` for a database, `MongoDB` assigns a `primary shard` for that database where `MongoDB` stores all data in that database.

Use the [sh.enableSharding()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/sh.enableSharding/#sh.enableSharding) method to enable sharding on the target database.

```
sh.enableSharding("<database>")
```

For further your ref [Here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2479), [Here](https://github.com/stefanprodan/mongo-swarm) & [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/N9YrEUNlA08)